# Can i save object inside liferay entity?

Tags: java, json, jax-rs, liferay-7

I have created liferay entity by service.xml. Can I save Json object inside string column and return this value like object from api? Now the response for "json" is this:

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "time": 1656067273906,
    "longitude": 00.00000,
    "latitude": 00.00000,
    "Json": "{"name":"test", "depth":"0", "main":"true", "power":"0"}",
    "description": "test",
}
```

But I hope to obtain "json" value without quotes, like this:

```
{
        "name": "test",
        "time": 1656067273906,
        "longitude": 00.00000,
        "latitude": 00.00000,
        "Json": {"name":"test", "depth":"0", "main":"true", "power":"0"},
        "description": "test",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the entity you wrote in `service.xml` has the `remote-service` attribute set to `true`, for example

```
<entity name="Employee" local-service="true" remote-service="true" uuid="true" trash-enabled="true">
```

and a text field named `info` (for example) in which you store a JSON string, then you can write a method in `<your service module src>/service/impl/EmployeeServiceImpl.java` that returns a JSONObject containing the data from your service entities. For example you can add a method to `EmployeeServiceImpl` class

```
public JSONObject myCustomMethod(long entityId) throws Exception {
    Employee employee EmployeeLocalServiceUtil.getEmployee(entityId);
    JSONObject result = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject();
    result.put("name", employee.getName());
    result.put("Json", JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject(employee.getInfo()));
    return result;
}
```

After that, run the `buildService` task then `build` and `deploy` your bundles. You will find `myCustomMethod` as JSONWS Api.